# how to display arrays using toast

Tags: android

I want to display an array of numbers using Toast function. But, it is accepting only strings. Is there any way to get rid of this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To detail the answer of @Daniel:

```
int[] myArray = new int[]{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
for(int i : myArray)
{
     builder.append("" + i + " ");
}
Toast.makeText(this, builder, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use a `StringBuilder` class to build the string you want from the array.

Answer (score 0):

It could be done simply by:

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), Arrays.toString(nameSend), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: Please, add some descritption  to the solution you are proposing.

Comment: nameSend is an Array, the function Arrays.toString() converts the Array to String

Comment: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.common.primitives.Ints"

Comment: if u have an array or an arraylist or an list there are two ways where u can convert them to string  
1. String.valueOf(Array)
2. Arrays.toString(Array)